# Difference in Schema and Data on BigQuery and Stack Exchange Data Explorer

Tags: google-bigquery, dataexplorer

There are two main ways to access the public dataset of StackOverflow as far as I am concerned: the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) and [BigQuery by Google](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/stack-exchange/stack-overflow?project=leafy-trainer-285023).

However, those two seem quite different, not only in that data explorer limits you to 50k lines of return. The underlying database schemes are also entirely different, with some information seemingly being lost in the BigQuery dataset.

As a practical problem I am encountering right now: I want to calculate the reputation history, thus get all reputation-affecting activities of a lot of users (think +30k users). However, some information e.g., badges seems to be only accessible in the data explorer.

Did anybody else run into this problem? Or am I just overseeing something obvious?

Thanks in advance.